# JMeterLibException: 'Incorrect log file format'

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

JMeter 2.12
python 2.7.18

I'm getting JMeterLibException: **'Incorrect log file format'** for the below code using robot framework

```
${logPath}= set variable    C:/Tests/output1.log    
run jmeter  C:/Tests/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/jmeter.bat C:/Tests/100users.jmx   ${logPath}
${result}   analyse jtl convert ${logPath}  
log ${result}       
FOR ${ELEMENT}  IN  @{result}
log dictionary  ${ELEMENT}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your "JMeterLib" (whatever it is) expects some specific JMeter [.jtl file format](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and JMeter 5.4.1 default settings are not compatible with it.

Unfortunately we cannot really help you without seeing this "JMeterLib" output or source code so I can only provide a generic piece of advice:

JMeter .jtl file output is controllable via special set of properties responsible for [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config), once you determine what exact metrics does your "JMeterLib" expect you can amend JMeter's configuration accordingly in order to make it compatible with your 3rd-party software assumptions.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [jtl](https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/JMeterLib.html) file extension instead of log

> ${logPath}=set variableD:/Tests/output1.jtl

Comment: I changed log to jtl file extension but still i have the same issue

Comment: @Solomon it seems from directory that you are using JMeter version 5.4.1 and not 2.12